# Custom sort Golang mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

I have orders table with schema

| SKU | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | IN_PROGRESS |
| 2 | DELIVERED |
| 3 | ON_DELIVERY |

I need to sort orders with custom way
so the in progress orders come first, then on delivery and finally delivered orders

the current query but need to be enhanced is

```
options.setSort(bson.D({"status", -1}))

model.Collection.Find(ctx, filter, options)
```

How to make model sort with this custom sort

I'm using golang with mongodb driver

Answer (score 1):

One option is to do custom sort by [`aggregate cond`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

Mongo query is

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {"$project":{
    "sortField":
      {"$cond":[{"$eq":["$status", "IN_PROGRESS"]}, 1,
      {"$cond":[{"$eq":["$status", "ON_DELIVERY"]}, 2,
      3]} ]},
    "status": true
  }},
  {"$sort":{"sortField": 1}}
]);
```

For collection data

```
db.products.insertMany([{"sku": 1, "status": "IN_PROGRESS"}, {"sku": 2, "status": "DELIVERED"}, {"sku": 3, "status": "ON_DELIVERY"}]);
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "sortField": 1,
    "status": "IN_PROGRESS"
  },
  {
    "sortField": 2,
    "status": "ON_DELIVERY"
  },
  {
    "sortField": 3,
    "status": "DELIVERED"
  }
]
```

---

And for golang mongo driver

```
    pipeline := []bson.M{
        {"$project": bson.M{"sortField": 
                    bson.M{"$cond": bson.A{bson.M{"$eq": bson.A{"$status", "IN_PROGRESS"}}, 1, 
                    bson.M{"$cond": bson.A{ bson.M{"$eq": bson.A{"$status", "ON_DELIVERY"}}, 2, 3}} }}, 
                    "status": true}},
        {"$sort": bson.M{"sortField": 1}},
    }
    model.Collection..Aggregate(context.Background(), pipeline)
```